# Import from .txt file and loop for ench IP

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I have a text file containing several IP adresses, which varies. I would like to run a code block for each IP in that file. But im kinda lost.

txt file looke like:

```
192.168.12.222
192.168.12.223
192.168.12.224
```

One IP per line, there could be hundreds.

I've been playing around with a foreach thing:

```
$nodes = Get-Content "\\Scripts\nodes.txt"
foreach-Object ($nodes) {

write-host $nodes #this should actually write the specific IP.
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can use a `C#` style `foreach ... in` loop:

```powershell
$nodes = Get-Content "\\Scripts\nodes.txt"
foreach($node in $nodes) {
  Write-Host $node
}
```

You can pipe `$nodes` to the `Foreach-Object`:

```powershell
$nodes | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

Or using the `%` shorthand for `ForEach-Object`:

```powershell
$nodes | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

`$_` is the variable that represents the current object in the pipeline